# UICategory - UIButtons and UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, xcode6

I want to create five buttons with same formats, so that i have created UICategory class for UIButton, But I don't get that category class calling, please help me on this,

My category class is as follows,

```
@implementation UIButton (headerBtn)
+(UIButton *)headerButtons{
UIButton *header = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[header setTitleColor:[UIColor headerBtnColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
header.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:Fonts_ProximaNovaMedium size:13.0f];
return header;}
```

Am calling button like as below,

```
btn_pulse                   =   [UIButton headerButtons];
```

is that correct way?

Comment: Is your category included in the same target as the code that is calling the category?

Comment: yes, I have created in same project only

Comment: Yes you are called category right way what is the issues in that?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
UIButton *header = [[UIButton alloc]init];
```

for

```
UIButton *header = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Anyway, I don't think you need a class method. I would do it this way:

```
@implementation UIButton (headerBtn)
-(void)headerStyle{
  [self setTitleColor:[UIColor headerBtnColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:Fonts_ProximaNovaMedium size:13.0f];
}
```

And the you just need to import your category and:

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] headerStyle];
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to import your category wherever you need it:

```
#import "UIButton+headerBtn.h"
```

Comment: Yes, I have imported, can you please tell me how to access that category and that created way was correct?

Comment: Looks correct. Have you added the +(UIButton *)headerButtons method in your UIButton+headerBtn.h file?

Comment: yeah, imported, here I wants this to be implemented into my further uibutton adding.